# Should we log CorrelationId in every logging line?

Tags: asp.net, .net, logging, serilog

I am working on implemeting Serilog for my Asp Dotnet application. I have come accross [this artilce](https://www.code4it.dev/blog/serilog-correlation-id/) on how to implement logging. Here is my understanding:

1. Create a unique Guid on every req from frontend. Add it as `x-correlation-id`.
2. On BE, create a middleware to add `x-correlation-id` if missing in request.

Que:

1. Should `x-correlation-id` be limited to logging only HTTP calls?
2. Should I also somehow loggin `x-correlation-id` for any log message that we have while certian methods are executed ? should we log on what happens inside controller ( Service call, CQRS ..) with the correlation id too ?

Answer (score 0):

`X-Correlation-Id` has now been largely supplanted by `traceparent`, a [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/) with recommendation status for distributed correlation.

[Serilog 3.1.*](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/releases/tag/v3.1.0) includes the necessary trace id and span id properties on every log event, if running in the context of a traced operation, so there's nothing additional needed there except to ensure your sink collects the trace and span ids.

[SerilogTracing](https://github.com/serilog-tracing/serilog-tracing/) extends Serilog with additional APIs for creating new traces/spans.